# Returning proper value from @AfterThrowing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am new to String, SpringBoot. 
Can we suppress thrown exception in a method annotated with `@AfterThrowing`?
I mean when an exception is thrown, it will suppress that and will return a default value on behalf of the invoking method?
Say, I have a controller -

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController implements IRestController{

    @Override
    @GetMapping("hello-throw")
    public String mustThrowException(@RequestParam(value = "name")final String name) throws RuntimeException {

        System.out.println("---> mustThrowException");
        if("Bakasur".equals(name)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("You are not welcome here!");
        }
        return name + " : Welcome to the club!!!";
    }
}
```

I have created a `@AspectJ`, as follows -

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.crsardar.handson.java.springboot.controller.IRestController.*(..))")
    public void executionPointcut(){

    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="executionPointcut()",
            throwing="th")
    public String afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable th){

        System.out.println("\n\n\tMyAspect : afterThrowing \n\n");

        return "Exception handeled on behalf of you!";
    }
}
```

If I run this & hit a ULR like - `http://localhost:8080/hello-throw?name=Bakasur`
I will get `RuntimeException`, but, I want to return a default message like - `Exception handeled on behalf of you!`, can we do it using `@AfterThrowing`?

I know it can be done using `@Around`, but around will be called on every hit of the url, that I do not want

Comment: This question is a duplicate, I answered it already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572489/1082681) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50040557/1082681). @KunalVohra, your link does **not** answer the question or "have all the info" because `@AfterThrowing` is not what the OP needs. He needs `@Around`.

Comment: @KunalVohra please read completely before response. I already read that block long time back

Comment: @kriegaex so the `@Around` is the only option?

Comment: If you want to do it via Spring AOP, yes. User @Simulant already told you about an alternative without AOP, just using Spring's exception handlers. Both ways are absolutely common in Spring, depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is Exception Handling on the controller. You don't need to build it yourself, Spring already supports you with some annotations like `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ControllerAdvice`. Best would be to follow this example: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  // 409
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

---

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
  public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

  @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView
  defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
    // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
    // the framework handle it - like the OrderNotFoundException example
    // at the start of this post.
    // AnnotationUtils is a Spring Framework utility class.
    if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation
                (e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
      throw e;

    // Otherwise setup and send the user to a default error-view.
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", e);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
    return mav;
  }
```

}

Comment: This answer is a solid and straightforward solution to the question. Thanks @Simulant

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fully qualified name of the class before method's name when you're referring to a pointcut. So, you should change @AfterThrowing something like this.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="packageName.MyAspect.executionPointcut()",
            throwing="th")
```

Please note that packageName is full package name of MyAspect.